# Qml listview add new row to a sub vector in the model

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have got a custom structure defined in C++, which contains several variables among them is a QList variable. I can now add a new structure dynamically in Qml listview, but my question is I also want to  add a new item into QList inside the structure, I can do this in the background but fail to update the listview.

I think the error appears in the connect() function in C++. As I understand in order to add a new row need to call beginInsertRows() and endInsertRows(), but should be sender and receiver be the same in these two scenarios?

So I have got the following structure in C++ along with some signals and functions used to insert new rows.

"todolist.h":

```
struct ToDoItem
{
    bool done;
    QString description;
    QList<int> list;

    ToDoItem(){
        done = false;
        description = "text";
        QList<int> mylist;
        mylist.append(1);
        list = mylist;
    }
};
signals:
    void preItemAppended();
    void postItemAppended();

    void preListAppended();
    void postListAppended();

public slots:
    void appendItem();
    void appendList();

void ToDoList::appendItem()
{
    emit preItemAppended();

    mItems.append(ToDoItem());
    emit postItemAppended();
}

void ToDoList::appendList()
{
    emit preListAppended();

    mItems[0].list.append(1);

    emit postListAppended();
}
```

"todomodel.h"

```
void ToDoModel::setList(ToDoList *list)
{
    beginResetModel();

    if (mList)
        mList->disconnect(this);

    mList = list;

    if (mList) {
        connect(mList, &ToDoList::preItemAppended, this, [=]() {
            const int index = mList->items().size();
            beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), index, index);
        });
        connect(mList, &ToDoList::postItemAppended, this, [=]() {
            endInsertRows();
        });

        connect(mList, &ToDoList::preListAppended, this, [=]() {
            const int index = mList->lists().size();
            beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), index, index);
        });
        connect(mList, &ToDoList::postListAppended, this, [=]() {
            endInsertRows();
        });
    }

    endResetModel();
}
```

The first two connect function works fine which are used to insert a new item but the second two connect functions fail.

Comment: please provide [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: Thanks for your help and I have added some code.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to connect signals to `beginInsertRows` and `endInsertRows`.
You should abstract that and rather connect to `add` or `remove` methods.
Assume you have your model class which implements `QAbstractListModel`:

```
class MyListModel : public QAbstractListModel {

  Q_OBJECT
  Q_PROPERTY(int size READ size NOTIFY sizeChanged)

  public:
  explicit myListModel(QObject *parent = nullptr);
  ~myListModel() override;

  int rowCount(const QModelIndex &p) const override;
  QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const override;
  QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const override;
  int size() const;

  public slots:
  void add(QObject *o);
  QObject *remove(int i);
  signals:
  void sizeChanged();

 private:
  QList<QObject *> m_data;

};
```

The implementation of `add` and `remove` wouldbe as follows:

```
void MyListModel::add(QObject* o) {
    int i = m_data.size();
    beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), i, i);
    m_data.append(o);
    o->setParent(this);
    sizeChanged();
    endInsertRows();
}


QObject * MyListModel::take(int i) {
    if ((i > -1) && (i < m_data.size())) {
        beginRemoveRows(QModelIndex(), i, i);
        QObject * o = m_data.takeAt(i);
        o->setParent(nullptr);
        sizeChanged();
        endRemoveRows();
        return o;
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

In this case, you can call `add` on newly added items, or if you're repopulating your list, you can clear it and loop over your list and add them 1 by 1.
**ADDING CUSTOM OBJECT EXAMPLE:**

```
class ToDoItem : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
  Q_PROPERTY(bool done READ done WRITE setDone NOTIFY doneChanged)

  public:
    explicit ToDoItem(QObject* parent = nullptr);
    ~ToDoItem() override;

    bool done() const { return m_done_; }
    void setDone(bool done) { m_done_ = done; emit doneChanged(done); }

  signals:
    void doneChanged(bool);

  private:
    bool m_done_;
};
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. But what if it is a customized class instead QObject, then I cannot use setParent(this), is it still able to use like this?

Comment: @user9016099 you can have your custom object that declares the macro `Q_OBJECT`, that way you can reuse this model in all your projects. I'm adding an example of a custom object above.

Comment: when you have the `Q_PROPERTY` in your object, you can simply refer to the property `done` inside the `listview`'s `delegate` as `model.modelData.done`. That is assuming that your `listview`'s `model` collection is of type `ToDoItem`.

Comment: what about the add function you provided above? Do I need to change anything?

Comment: what issues are you seeing?

Comment: as the add() function requires a QObject*, how can I turn this into a custom class? Or otherwise I won't be able to use o->setParent(this)

Comment: the add function will be called on the model and you can pass `ToDoItem*` which is of type `QObject*` (as in my example) to it. I encourage you to try it and ask questions when you encounter a problem you tried to solve and couldn't :)

Comment: sorry about that! And I have tried this time. I wonder if I can call it in qml file? Sorry it might be quite stupid.

Comment: you can. here's an example from the docs. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-contextproperties.html. In your case your model can be set as a context property.

Comment: yeah I know this. What I am saying is in order to call add() we need to call it like add(QObject) right? How can I get something like QObject in qml?

Comment: I would create a helper class in c++ that gets calls from QML. Create your model in main and pass it to that class. When QML needs to add items you can pass a map of properties through the helper class. There you can do `ToDoItem *it = new ToDoItem;` and set the parameters with the properties, and add the new object to your model.